# How to play a song on clicking on list of songs?

Tags: windows-phone-8, media-player, media-library

I have a media player project for my course. I have a list songs:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxSongs" SelectionChanged="listBoxSongs_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="100"  Margin="8" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                            <StackPanel >
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Title}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Artist}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Duration}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The code below uses media library and shows list of songs with listview:

```
 foreach (Song song in songs)
        {
            if (song != null)
                mySongs.Add(new MySongs()
                {
                    Artist = song.Artist.ToString(),
                    Title = song.Name,
                    Duration = (new DateTime(song.Duration.Ticks)).ToString("mm:ss")
                });
            else
            {

                TextBlock msg = new TextBlock();

                msg.Text = "no music";
                listBoxSongs.Items.Add(msg);
            }
            if (song.Album.HasArt)
            {
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

                img.SetSource(song.Album.GetAlbumArt());
                mySongs.Last().Image = img;
            }
            else
                mySongs.Last().Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/noArt.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        listBoxSongs.ItemsSource = mySongs;
```

How to navigate to "mainPage.xaml" and play a song from my list when I click on listview Item?

Comment: MediaPlayer.Play(YourSong);

Comment: You need to add SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSong,mode="TwoWay"} and just do this => MediaPlayer.PlaySong(SelectedItem);

Comment: @MatDev8 sorry, I'm newbie, I do not know where to add SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSong,mode="TwoWay"}and i don't find "MediaPlayer.PlaySong()" I have a MediaElement in the main page. <MediaElement Name="media"  AutoPlay="False"/>. Can you provide detailed guidance. thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: You don't need to add mediaplayer control in your main page, MediaPlayer is a static class for use the phone media player.